# Prevent user from input after reaching maxAllowed characters in Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a textarea field which should have 300 characters allowed maximum. And after that is reached user could not enter any character.

```
{
    padding: '10 10 10 10',
    colspan: 2,
    flex: 1,
    xtype: 'textareafield',
    grow: true,
    name: 'Text1',
    fieldLabel: 'Text',
    width: '90%',
    anchor: '100%',
    maxLength: 300,
    disabled: true
},
```

But I can insert as many characters as I want. However form validation fails if user enters more than 300 chars. But still user should be able to enter no more than 300 in textarea field.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [enforceMaxLength](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.form.field.TextArea.html#cfg-enforceMaxLength) property on `TextAreaField` will do that for you

Default value is `flase` but make it `true` to set the `maxLength` property on the underlying input field as says in document